# laravel: passing object into d3.cal-heatmap

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I want to build a data variable containing the number of occurrences of unix datetime values.

i.e.

```
{1489140000.0: 2, 1487239200.0: 1, 1483524000.0: 2, 1486634400.0: 1, 1490086800.0: 3 }
```

My error is that on the view I'm getting `laravel use of undefined constant datas - assumed 'datas'`

```
public function showStatistics()
{
    $job_post_date = Emploi::where('language', 'EN')->pluck('POSTDATE');
    $unix_time = array();

    for ($i=0; $i < count($job_post_date) ; $i++) { 
        $unix_time[$i] = strtotime($job_post_date[$i]);
    }

    $datas = array_count_values($unix_time);
    $datas = json_encode($datas);

    return view('emploi.stats', ['datas' => $datas]);
}
```

excerpt of a javascript part in the stats.blade.php

```
....
var cal = new CalHeatMap();
cal.init({
    itemSelector: "#example-d",
    domain: "month",
  itemName: ["job", "jobs"],
    data:  {!! datas !!},
    start: thisMonth.SubtractMonth(5),
    cellSize: 12,
    cellPadding: 5,
    ....
```

I'm getting an error in the template on: {{ datas }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
data:  {!! $datas !!}
```

instead of

```
data:  {!! datas !!}
```

You missed the dollar sign, which makes PHP assume it's a constant (which you don't declare).

Comment: thanks @lessugar! can you update it to be {!! $datas !!} instead so that it's a proper javascript object. {"1497571200":3,"1497484800":5,...}, otherwise it will escape the quotes

Comment: Sure. Done on your post as well.